# Create a longtable with 3 columns, textwidth size that can span 2 page and still can be readable

Tags: tables, longtable, code

I need to create a table with 3 columns and many words in all three of them which can be readable. I am using tabularray enviroment and putting colours to each column. Unofrtunately because of the words my table passes the textwidth limits and is not clearly viewed. If I use resizebox command then it works but the letter font is so small in the table, that it is not readable anymore. The main idea down was to create tabular for each input of text so that it can follow a direction vertically like for example in Illustrator or Powerpoint.This improved the font size but still it is small. I searched a bit and found that a possible way is to create a longtable. unfortunately I dont know how to do this properly. I ended up when i tried longtable in a colourful table which expanded to the second page as I wish but could not fit in the dimensions of the text (so  textwidth was more than what it should be).

The code I have written and works now looks like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%margins remove huge, outdated printing margins
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
%set vertical margins
\setlength{\topmargin}{2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16,5cm}
\usepackage{cite}%Βιβλιογραφία
\usepackage{tabularray} %pinakes
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}%pinakes

\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \centering
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tblr}{
                    colspec={|l|c|c|}, hlines={1pt, black}, vlines={1pt, black}, column{1} = {yellow!50}, column{2} = {blue!40},
                    column{3} = {magenta!20}
                }   
                \toprule
                \textbf{XXXX} & \SetCell[c=1]{c} \textbf{XXXX} & \SetCell[c=1]{c} \textbf{XXXX} \\ 
                \midrule
                \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX\\ XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline  
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\textsuperscript{\textregistered} XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX, XXXX \end{tabular} \\  & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX\\ \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} \\ \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX, 99\% \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline 
                \begin{tabular}{l}\texttrademark{XXXX} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ XXXX \\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}\texttrademark{XXXX} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX\\ XXXX \\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l} XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline 
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\textsuperscript{\textregistered} Pro \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} &\begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX,\\XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX,\\ XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}\texttrademark{XXXX} XXXX, XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\textsuperscript{\textregistered}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX \\ \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}XXXX\\ \end{tabular} \\ 
                \hline         
                \bottomrule
            \end{tblr}
        }
        \caption{Guybrush Threepwood is a mighty pirate}
        \label{Table C}
\end{table}
```

This is more or less what I want to achieve
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can make your question more comprehensible by formatting your code.  Highlight it using your mouse, then click on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: you need to remove `begin{table}` and `\resizebox` both prevent page breaks, (always avoid `\resizebox` on tables)

Comment: PLease, extend your code snippet to complete small document, which can be compiled as it is. SO far code fragment is not completed and contain errors.

Comment: Yur code still not work.

Comment: Why do you have all these `tabular`s inside the `tblr`? That's weird.

Comment: If i did not do this...then the text inside each raw was only expanding on the right and not vertically. So it was even tougher to create the table. It was proposed somewhere here. Sorry I am not an experience user so I try and follow guidelines , but this of course can also lead to errors...

Comment: What is purpose of your table? Test, if this artificial words can be broken in several lines? IN `tabular` will not, even, if you remove them, also will not. Please provide more natural cells contents.

Comment: Dear Zarko the purpose is to create a simple table in a colourful powepoint format with text in every box which will consist of 3 columns and 20 rows.... and start on page 1 and finish on page 2 of the document that I am generating . The content is irrelevant thats why I put an XXXXXX ..... important is the form and how to generate it. I literrally want to recreate a powepoint table in an essence, nothing fancy. Only thing I want is to for the text to be large enough to be read and for my table to be with colourful. Nothing fancy I am still learning.

Comment: @Lechuck21, but then break this text on shorter sequence (two to six letters). Or write some dummy text with natural words, which can be hyphenate. You will get readable table only in case, if you will allow that long cells text can be broken in multiple lines.

Comment: @Zarko I tried this by for example writing in one raw  \begin{tabular}{l} I used to go to school \\ but then I started play the bass \\ and wanted to become a bassist \\ \end{tabular} &  ..... & ....... .Still by breaking text in the long cells the result was not good enough unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, so I (only) guess, that you like to obtain something similar to following table example (where for cells' text are used dummy text generated by `lipsum` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tblr}{hlines={1pt, fg=white}, vlines={1pt, fg=white}, 
            colspec={X[l,bg=yellow!80] 
                     X[c,bg=blue!40] 
                     X[c,bg=magenta!20]},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries, c, fg=white}
             }
column 1        &  columm 2         & column 3          \\
%
\lipsum[1][1-1] &\lipsum[1][1-1]    &\lipsum[1][1-1]    \\
\lipsum[1][1-1] &\lipsum[1][1-1]    &\lipsum[1][1-1]    \\
\lipsum[1][1-1] &\lipsum[1][1-1]    &\lipsum[1][1-1]    \\
\lipsum[1][1-1] &\lipsum[1][1-1]    &\lipsum[1][1-1]    \\
\lipsum[1][1-1] &\lipsum[1][1-1]    &\lipsum[1][1-1]    \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{
 GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD IS A MIGHTY PIRATE or THE PIRATE i WAS MEANT TO BE}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I your table is really very long and need to span several pages, than you need to use `longtblr`. For example with the following preamble:

```
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {A caption at long table is usual on the top of table},
  label ={tab:long?}
                ]{
        hlines={1pt, fg=white}, vlines={1pt, fg=white}, 
        colspec={X[l,bg=yellow!80] 
                 X[c,bg=blue!40] 
                 X[c,bg=magenta!20]},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries, c, fg=white},
        rowhead=1
                }
column 1        &  column 2         & column 3          \\
%
% table body
%
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

- as you can see, in example are not used construct `\begin{table}{l} ... \end{table}` it only overwrite seeting of columns. If you like to manulaly split text in cell, than use `tabularray` syntax for this `{text in the first line\\ text in the second line}`
- please consider comments below your question. Basic of table writing you can fine for example on [wiki: tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), package `tabularray` have good short documentation. It is worth to read it.

**Edit:**
Provided solution use `tabularray` package as  @cabohah use in his answer, which was published 28 minutes before mine. His is interesting, but both answers has common only use the same package for writing of tables.

Main differences between both suggestion are in style definitions in table preamble, not used `\midrule` between rows in table body and consequently obtained table style (so far) quite different (to my opinion much closer to what OP like to get).

Comment: thank you very much. Yes the longtable is what I need, plus I would like that the genereated table can be listed on a seperate list of tables of the document. I am starting using this package now. thank you.

Comment: @Lechuck21, sorry, your comment is not clear. We still don't know, what is your problem. If my answer help you or solve some your problem(s), consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer). By this you will informe site members, that your problem is solve. If you will have new problems, don't hesitate to ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `longtblr` for tables with page breaks. But you cannot put such a table inside a float like `table`.

`tabularray` provides column type `X` for columns with line breaks. But to be able to break columns, the text should allow hyphenation. Because your text often is not, I've added several hyphenation marks `\-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}% Loads caption
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec={|X|X|X|},
    hlines={1pt, black},
    vlines={1pt, black},
    column{1} = {yellow!50},
    column{2} = {blue!40},
    column{3} = {magenta!20},
    caption = {GUYBRUSH THREEPWOOD IS A MIGHTY PIRATE or THE PIRATE i WAS
      MEANT TO BE},
    label = {tab:first}
}   
\toprule
\textbf{xixiixxi} & \SetCell[c=1]{c} \textbf{xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-} & \SetCell[c=1]{c} \textbf{solsolsolsolsol} \\ 
\midrule
blahhahhhhhhhhhhhhh & blAHHHHHHHHHHHH & BLA\-HHHHHHHHH \\
\midrule
blahhh\textsuperscript{\textregistered} BLA\-HHHHHHHHH & blahhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh \\ 
\midrule
blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  \\  & Iblahhhhhhhh  & blahhhhhhhhhhh  \\
\midrule
blajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj & blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  & BLA\-HHHHHHHHHH  \\ \midrule
blahhhhhhhhhh  & BLA\-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH  & BLA\-HHHHHHHHHH  \\ 
\midrule 
\texttrademark{blahhhhhh} xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-  & xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\-xa\- & xo\-xo\-xo\-xo\-xo\-oxo\-xo\-xo\-xxo\- HIHIHIHIHIHIHHII  \\ 
\midrule
\texttrademark{solalalalal} ka\-ka\-ka\-ka\-ka\-ka\-ka\-ka\-  & kokokokokokookokok & KI\-KI\-KI\-KI\-KI\-KKI\-KI\-KI\-KI\-RIRIRIRRIRIRIKOU  \\
\midrule
LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-L  & LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-L  & FFA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-FA\-A \\ 
\midrule
ISSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSS  & SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SS & SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSS \\ 
\midrule 
AAAA\-AAAA\-AAAA\-AAAA\-AA\textsuperscript{\textregistered} AAA  & AAAA\-AAAA\-AAAA\-AA
&AAAA\-AAAA\-AAAA\-AAAA\-AA \\
SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\- & & \\
\midrule
oooooooooooooooo  & bambamabmabamabam & OLA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-L \\ 
\midrule
SADASDSADSADSADSADASDSA & & \\
DADADADADADADADADADA  & DADADADADADADADADA & XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XXXX\-XX \\
\midrule
kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-kkkk\-  & llllllllllllllll & yyyy\-yyyy\-yyyy\-yyyy\-yyyy\-yyyy\-yyyy\-y \\
\midrule
SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-  & gaga\-gaga\-gaga\-gaga\-gaga\-ga & TIROUR\-IROIRORU\-TORU\-TORUT \\ 
\midrule
LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\-  & LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-LA\-ALA\-LA\-LA\- & keke\-keke\-keke\-keke\-keke\-keke\-k \\
\midrule
\texttrademark{sssssssn}poppopppppppppppppp  & aaaaaa\-aaaaaa\-aaaaaaa & xxxxx\-xxxx\-xxxxx \\ 
\midrule
SADASDASDASDASD\textsuperscript{\textregistered}20 SSSSSS\-SSD.  & AAAA\-\-AAAA\-AAAA\- & dSSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SSSSSS\-SS \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

See the `tabularray` manual for more information about column type `X`, captions, repeated captions with page breaks etc.

Comment: Sorry for unclear comment.  It was based on OP's provide MWE, which not repšroduce show image of table.  So I will delete ti (since it is impossible to edit it). About stealing, hm that is harsh accuse! Yes, I use `tabularray` package too, but the table code if  quite different with more correct `tabularray` syntax. BTW, according to your reputation, you not just novice. If you will add image of table produced by your MWE, I will happy to upvote your answer.

Comment: See edit in my answer!

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, I didn't know that only answers with images can be up-voted on tex.stackexchange.com. I'm really to new here (this answer was my 11th or 12th) to know this and cannot find such an information in the help. Will try to not forget it in future. Thanks for the note.

Comment: That is my condition for your answer. anyone can upvote how (s)he wish ... I just like to see image of table, for comparison.